# Jquery On Scroll not working with new element created

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery 1.9.1 . This code is for capture the scroll event when someone scroll the div in class "myclass".

```
$('.myclass').on('scroll', function() {
alert('test');
});
```

This work well with which element already have in page load. But when i using .append to create a new element :

```
$("body").append("<div class='myclass'> some large text to show the scrollbar ....</div>');
```

This new element will not fire any scroll event. How to resolve this problem ?

---

Updated the JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/R6UH7/2/

Comment: Just updated my answer. A bit more code but will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually the events `load`, `error` and `scroll` do not bubble up the DOM. So you need another approach. The best I can think of is to add the listeners again... Like this:

```
function scrollfunc() {
    alert('test');
};

function listen_again() {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass");
    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i].onscroll = scrollfunc;
    }
}

function apdDiv() {
    $("body").append('<div class="myclass" >This is another div that using append<br>This is another div that using append</div>');
    listen_again()
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    apdDiv();
    listen_again()
});
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/AAxrE/)**

Comment: your solution causes the alert to be triggered twice

Comment: just remove the first .scroll event and leave only the function apdDiv and the dom ready and it works as expected

Comment: you are calling listen_again() twice :D and np

Comment: @Krotz, yes. The OP will have to adapt to his code. I call it on `.ready()` just for the example. But all is in different functions so he can adapt.

Comment: It's work well, amazing ! Thank Sergio, Krotz and J_Caselles. All of solution work but i think the solution from Sergio is the best way !

Answer (score 0):

"In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an  element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event."

Don't know exactly what they mean with directly attached but my first thought is that you can't  scroll delegate dynamic data only those already existent.

**Try this thanks to @Sergio**

```
function apdDiv() {
    $("body").append('<div class="myclass" >This is another div that using append<br>This is another div that using append</div>');
    $('.myclass').scroll(function () {
        alert('test');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    apdDiv();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VGVZJ/1/

**This does not work with multiple appends!**

Comment: This was a trycky problem, anyway your solution (that I also though about as you mention) works for 1 append, if OP appends more times it generates many alerts... check here: http://jsfiddle.net/VGVZJ/2/

Comment: well, I also missed it first :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the on() function after the append.

```
$("body").append('<div class="myclass" >This is another div that using append<br>This is another div that using append</div>');
$('.myclass').on('scroll', function() {
alert('test');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R6UH7/5/

Selecting "myclass" elements only happens once. If you select before you create the new one, you can't bind this event to the future div.

from **on()** documentation:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()